# I have Code to get date and time then display it but how do I make it refresh itself in svelte

Tags: javascript, html, svelte

This is my code
I get all the info I need but it only updates itself when I refresh the window I want it to update automatically every second

```
<script>
        const d = new Date();
    
        let date = d.getDate()
        let month = d.getMonth();
        let year = d.getFullYear();
        let hour = d.getHours();
        let minute = d.getMinutes();
        let second = d.getSeconds();
    </script>
    
    <main>
        <div class="hero min-h-screen bg-base-200">
            <div class="hero-content text-center">
              <div class="max-w-md">
                <h1 class="text-8xl font-bold">{date}/{month}/{year}</h1>
                <br>
                <h1 class="text-8xl font-bold">{hour}:{minute}:{second}</h1>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    </main>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to re-assign the variables periodically, e.g. using `setInterval`, using a new `Date` each time. Note, that if you use exactly one second as an interval, changes could be missed due to shift/slight delays.

Implementing an accurate and efficient timer is an interesting problem of its own, there is an entire [HTTP 203 episode on that](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MCi6AZMkxcU). Jake's implementation is this (made `signal` optional):

```js
export function animationInterval(ms, signal, callback) {
  // Prefer currentTime, as it'll better sync animtions queued in the 
  // same frame, but if it isn't supported, performance.now() is fine.
  const start = document.timeline ? document.timeline.currentTime : performance.now();

  function frame(time) {
    if (signal?.aborted) return;
    callback(time);
    scheduleFrame(time);
  }

  function scheduleFrame(time) {
    const elapsed = time - start;
    const roundedElapsed = Math.round(elapsed / ms) * ms;
    const targetNext = start + roundedElapsed + ms;
    const delay = targetNext - performance.now();
    setTimeout(() => requestAnimationFrame(frame), delay);
  }

  scheduleFrame(start);
}
```

So it could be used like this:

```html
<script>
    import { animationInterval } from './animation.js';

    let date, month, year, hour, minute, second;
    function update() {
        const d = new Date();
        date = d.getDate()
        month = d.getMonth();
        year = d.getFullYear();
        hour = d.getHours();
        minute = d.getMinutes();
        second = d.getSeconds();
    }
    
    update();
    animationInterval(1000, undefined, update);
</script>

<h1 class="text-8xl font-bold">{date}/{month}/{year}</h1> <br>
<h1 class="text-8xl font-bold">{hour}:{minute}:{second}</h1>
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/3859902f58014b4fbebd44bd8bd81e16?version=3.48.0)

Comment: Seems to be working but it does throw an error
ReferenceError: document is not defined

Comment: If you use server-side rendering, e.g. in SvelteKit, you need to wrap the last two lines in `onMount`, so that only runs in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *setInterval* to execute code. For example, if you want the code to re-execute every 1 second.

```js
function printTime() {
  const date = new Date();
  console.log( date.toString() );
}

//          function    time (in ms)
setInterval(printTime(), 1000);
```

(Note; StackOverflow's code snippet will only execute setInterval once.)